# extract date and time from datetime using javascript

Tags: javascript

My time format is given below

```
var time = "2013-08-07 20:53:35"
```

I  need to get the date `"2013-08-07"` as `07.08.2013` and time `"20:53:35"` as `20:53:35`.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you should

- first separate date and time using `split(" ")`
- Then `split()` date by `"-"`
- Use `reverse()` on the date array and `join` it using `.`

```js
var time = "2013-08-07 20:53:35"
let arr = time.split(' ');
let date = arr[0].split('-').reverse().join('-');
let tm = arr[1]
console.log(date)
console.log(tm)
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how much of this you will be doing I would highly recommend look at moment.js.  You can download from npm if a nodejs app or just use from a cdn if browser based javascript.  Here is a sample:

```
var time = "2013-08-07 20:53:35"
var newdate = moment(time).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
var newtime = moment(time).format("HH:mm:ss");
document.writeln(newdate);
document.writeln(newtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using core javascript

```
function formatDate(datetime) {
     var date = new Date(datetime);
     var hours = date.getHours();
     var minutes = date.getMinutes();
     var seconds = date.getSeconds();
     var strTime = hours+':'+minutes+ ':' + seconds;

     return ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)  +  "." +('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + "."+ date.getFullYear() + "  " + strTime;
}

console.log(formatDate('2013-08-07 20:53:35'));
```

https://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

http://jsfiddle.net/p2wLrov4/2/